# Antroid 5 bitmap drawing trouble

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap

Wrote view with background rendering to `Bitmap`. Code below, it's big, but simple. Two bitmaps. One to draw on the screen, second for custom draw. After drawing is done, bitmaps are switched.

On Android 4.x everything works fine. On Android 5 everything is slow, has large lags and log messages:

> Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

If in the procedures `drawThread()` just remove the line: `synchronized (this) {useBMP = n; }` or remove bitmap switching via `if(useBMP == 0) n = 0;` everything works smoothly and quickly! Certainly - with artifacts.

I'm stuck, I can not understand why. Interested in any idea and any information that may help.

```
public class TouchView extends ScrollView {
    volatile int useBMP;
    Bitmap    cacheBMP[];
    boolean   startDraw, exitDraw;

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        cacheBMP = new Bitmap[2];
    }

    protected void  onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        for( int i=0; i<2; i++ )
            cacheBMP[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(w*2, h*2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        useBMP=0;
        startDraw = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        exitDraw = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {  drawThread();  }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        exitDraw = true;

        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    void drawThread() {
        int  n;
        while( !exitDraw ) {
            if( startDraw ) {
                startDraw = false;

                if( useBMP==0 )  n=1;
                else             n=0;

                drawBMP(n);

                synchronized (this) { useBMP = n; }
                postInvalidate();
            }

            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void drawBMP(int n) {
        cacheBMP[n].eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cacheBMP[n]);
      .....
    }

    public void redraw() {
        startDraw = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        synchronized (this) {
                c.drawBitmap(cacheBMP[useBMP],0,0,p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant you remove the synchronized from the onDraw? He will wait for any thread that has the LOCK

Comment: Yes,  I tried remove synchronized block - nothing changed. Android 4 keep working, Android 5 keep lagging

Comment: You're overwriting the bitmap while the GUI thread is using it, that can't be good and android 5 is probably just handling that more correctly by locking somewhere.  Just wait for the GUI thread to finish its intervention before reusing the bitmap. If nothing else you'll do less useless work

Comment: Not. I using 2 bitmaps. One for GUI thread another for drawing procedure. If I remove bitmaps switch and using one bitmap for GUI and drawing - everything work quick and smoothly. But with corruption drawing on the screen.

Comment: @Gennady There's an obvious race condition there: T1 draws  bitmap 0 and calls `invalidate`. T1 draws bitmap 1 and calls `invalidate` again. T1 starts working on bitmap 0. T0 uses bitmap 0 and conflicts with T1. And that assumes nothing can cause `onDraw` to be called except the invalidate in your own code.

Comment: @Voo Not. There's not race. onDraw just draw current bitmap assigned to GUI. Does not matter what Draw-thread does. Even if it switches the bitmaps during operation onDraw. But synchronized block prevent this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems disappear if to create bitmaps RGB_565.
This is not a solution, but indicates that the problem is bitmaps drawing not multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you remove the synchronized from the onDraw? He will wait for any thread that has the LOCK